# Choosing coordinate reference system (CRS) for the European Alps

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, europe

I am looking for a suitable projected coordinate reference system (CRS) for the European Alps.

Requirements:

- Extent: Covering the whole European Alps: Horizontal: 4.5°...17° Vertical: 43°...48.5°.
- Isogonal projection. As far as mathematically possible the projection should be as well equidistant.
- One common zone.
- Unit: Meters (m)
- EPSG code available

Comment: What have you tried, and why did you reject them? As written, this may be too *opinion-based* to avoid closure, so please [Edit] the question.

Comment: This source may help you: http://crs.bkg.bund.de/homepage.htm

Answer (score 1):

Go to EPSG registry (https://epsg.org/)

Do a map search by drawing a polygon around the area of interest, and you will have a selection of CRS to choose from that match your criteria